# Discovering the time difference between sets of data

Tags: c++, function, file, conditional-statements, std

So I'm currently working with a data file that holds data for different rabbits, where a rabbit's given number is the first entry of every line in the file. The other data in the file is as follows: time rabbit is seen, angle of rabbit's position in the yard (around a 360 degree radius), and the distance of the rabbit to the camera. The file is shown here:

```
8 001218 82.4 7.6
8 001233 76.2 9.9
8 001259 120.4 12.1
8 001305 120.4 12.6
12 013618 217 1.2
12 013714 64 1.1
12 013802 64 1.1
12 013942 33.8 13.4
2 042688 306 3.9
3 052222 5.6 8.9
3 052700 272.2 12.1
17 235516 42.0 7.6
17 235922 18.2 7.6
17 000118 36.4 7.6
17 000226 291.3 7.6
```

So I currently am able to output each rabbit number, the time (in proper hh:mm:ss format), and the (x,y) coordinate of the rabbit in the yard. The code I have is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int hours(int time_hhmmss)
{
    return time_hhmmss/10000;
}

int minutes(int time_hhmmss)
{
    return (time_hhmmss % 10000) / 100;
}

int seconds(int time_hhmmss)
{
    return time_hhmmss % 100;
}

double x_coordinate(double heading, double distance)
{
    return distance*cos(heading * M_PI / 180);
}

double y_coordinate(double heading, double distance)
{
    return distance*sin(heading * M_PI / 180);  
}

int get_duration(int start_hours, int start_minutes, int start_seconds, 
         int end_hours, int end_minutes, int end_seconds)
{   
    int change_in_hours = (end_hours - start_hours) * 3600;
    int change_in_minutes = (end_minutes - start_minutes) * 60;
    int change_in_seconds = end_seconds - start_seconds;

    return change_in_hours + change_in_minutes + change_in_seconds;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("wascally_wabbits.txt");
    ofstream fout("wabbit_data.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Unable to find the file..." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int rabbitNumber = 0, int rabbitNumber = 0, count = 0, hour1 = 0, hour2 
    = 0, minute1 = 0, 
    minute2 = 0, second1 = 0, second2 = 0;;

    while (fin >> rabbitNumber)
{   
    count += 1;

    fout << rabbitNumber << " "; 

    int time = 0;
    fin >> time;

    int hour = hours(time);
    int minute = minutes(time);
    int second = seconds(time);

    fout << hour << ":" << minute << ":" << second << " ";

    double heading = 0, distance = 0;
    fin >> heading >> distance;

    double x = x_coordinate(heading, distance);
    double y = y_coordinate(heading, distance);

    fout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "( " << x << " , " << y << " )";

    if (count += 1)
    {
        int hour1 = hour;
        int minute1 = minute;
        int second1 = second;
    }

    if (count += 2)
    {
        int hour2 = hour;
        int minute2 = minute;
        int second2 = second;

        int duration = get_duration(hour1, minute1, second1, hour2, minute2, second2);

        fout << " " << duration << endl;

        hour1 = 0, minute1 = 0, second1 = 0, hour2 = 0, minute2 = 0, second2 = 0, count = 0;
    }
}

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I think all of my functions are working in proper order, but I'm struggling with being able to get the duration.

The duration is essentially the time difference between data entries for a specific rabbit (so rabbit 8, for instance), so if I had a time of 00:12:18 and the next being 00:12:33, I would get 15 seconds as the time difference.

I have sort of got it to work, where my output file is as such:

```
8 0:12:18 ( 1.01 , 7.53 ) 738
8 0:12:33 ( 2.36 , 9.61 ) 753
8 0:12:59 ( -6.12 , 10.44 ) 779
8 0:13:5 ( -6.38 , 10.87 ) 785
12 1:36:18 ( -0.96 , -0.72 ) 5778
12 1:37:14 ( 0.48 , 0.99 ) 5834
12 1:38:2 ( 0.48 , 0.99 ) 5882
12 1:39:42 ( 11.14 , 7.45 ) 5982
2 4:26:88 ( 2.29 , -3.16 ) 16048
3 5:22:22 ( 8.86 , 0.87 ) 19342
3 5:27:0 ( 0.46 , -12.09 ) 19620
17 23:55:16 ( 5.65 , 5.09 ) 86116
17 23:59:22 ( 7.22 , 2.37 ) 86362
17 0:1:18 ( 6.12 , 4.51 ) 78
17 0:2:26 ( 2.76 , -7.08 ) 146
```

In this file output I'm basically seeing that the time difference is the next minus the previous, so from the first line I would have 753 - 738 = 15 seconds (so that's at least the right time difference).

However, I'm struggling with being able to make sure the first entry (so for rabbit 8, rabbit 12, etc.) is 0, and that it outputs the proper time difference value.

I'm not looking for you to answer my question, but I've been thinking about this for hours and I've gotten nowhere so if anyone has an idea of how it could work better that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're able to print that difference (753 - 738 = 15) correctly, then you must be retaining the 738 when you read the 753 line. If you also retain the rabbit number, then you can detect the appearance of a new rabbit (e.g. one line is an 8 and the next is a 12). Then all you have to do is define the behavior you want in that case.

Comment: You want to output the duration of what exactly?

Comment: @n.m. The duration is essentially just the time difference between one data reading to another.

Comment: @Beta Hmm... yeah that is true. I was just struggling with like getting the different lines. If I wanted to make sure I calculated everything for rabbit 8 would I maybe use a while loop inside of my while(fin >> rabbitNumber), that checked for something like a currentRabbit?

Comment: Between which two readings? Any two, or two successive readings, or two successive readings for the same rabbit?